# Proof dot product identity

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, inner-products

From the **dot product** properties we can write:

$$
\langle v, u \rangle = v^{T} u = \sum_{j}^{} u_j v_j
$$

I want to **prove** that:

$$
\langle v, u \rangle u = (u u^{T}) v 
$$

I tried rewriting the first expression as

$$ 
\langle v, u \rangle u  = (v^{T} u)u = \cdots =  (u u^{T}) v  
$$

But I don't know how to continue to reach the right hand side. Is this approach the right way?

Comment: Hint: apply the associative property of matrix multiplication to the product $uu^\top v$. Note that $u^\top v$ is a scalar!

Comment: @Botond Yes, that seems to be true, as $\;u^t\;$ seems to be a *row vector*...Deleting.

Comment: @DonAntonio I think they are column vectors, because the result of the "dot product" would not be a scalar with row vectors.

Comment: $\langle v,u\rangle u = u\langle u,v\rangle=uu^Tv$.

Comment: @Botond Exactly, and thus $\;u^t\;$ is a row vector...

Comment: @runway44 it seems to be pretty right actually. Thanks :)

Comment: This requires a bit of an algebraic dodge since, strictly speaking, _right_ multiplication of a vector by a scalar isn’t defined by the vector space axioms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $i$-th component of $\langle v, u \rangle u$ is
$$\sum_j v_ju_j u_i$$
While the $i$-th component of $(u u^t) v$ is
$$\sum_{j} (uu^t)_{ij}v_j=\sum_j u_iu_jv_j$$

Comment: How did you do the last step? Just thinking about the rows?

Comment: @Ergo Which step? $(u u^t)_{ij}=u_iu_j$?

Comment: Yes exactly that

Comment: @Ergo it comes from the definition of matrix multiplication. To see it, calculate $u u^t$ for $u=(u_1,u_2)^t$. Or you can use the definition of matrix multiplication: $(AB)_{ij}=\sum_{k}A_{ik}B_{kj}$. If the number of columns of $A$ and the number of rows of $B$ is 1, the sum will only have 1 element: $(AB)_{ij}=A_{i1}B_{1j}$.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

We have$\, \langle v, u \rangle u = u \langle u, v \rangle = 
u (u^{T} v) = (u u^{T})v \,$ where the first equality is commutativity
of multiplication of a scalar times a vector. The second equality by
definition of dot (or inner) product. The third equality by associativity of
multiplicaton of matrices and vectors.